# Passing value between 2 dropdowns onchange. Update without click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dropdown

I'm trying to build 2 separate dropdown selector with same value of options (same text)

selector 1
selector 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">


jQuery(function ($) {
var $set = $('#selector1, #selector2')
$set.change(function () {
    $set.not(this).val(this.value)
})

})
</script>

<html> 
 <div style="float: right;margin-left: 10px;">
                    <div >
                    <select id="selector1" onchange="" 
 style="width:130px;">
                      <option selected diabled hidden value="">Select Volume 
 Type</option>
                        <option value="1">Auto-Weekly</option>
                        <option value="2">Auto-Monthly</option>
                        <option value="3">Custom Weekly</option>
                              <option value="4">Custom Monthly</option>

                    </select></div>
                </div>
<td style="text-align: center;">

<select id="selector2" style="width:80px;">
<option selected="" diabled="" hidden="" value="0">Select Report 
Period</option>
                        <option value="1">Auto-Weekly</option>
                        <option value="2">Auto-Monthly</option>     
                            <option value="3">Custom Weekly</option>   
                             <option value="4">Custom Monthly</option>        
                    </select>

                            </td>


</html>
```

Problem:
Now I have used the javascript above to match the value from $set.
The issue is that I have to 'click' onto the dropdown in order to 'update'. 
For example, 
if i selected option value=1 in selector1, then i have to 'click' selector2 to see the updated value.

Could you please help if there are more refined solution? I am using these options differently later on, that's why I need 2 separate selectors and match them through binding.

Comment: Now you need to update the same value in selector2 as soon as you change a value in selector one right?

Comment: yes, current requires that i 'click' to start onchange to grab the value.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried following script, but it still required that i click to update the dropdown value.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selector1, #selector2').on('change',function() 
{   
 var report_answer = jQuery('#selector1').val();
 var report_type = jQuery('#selector2').val();  



var x=  document.getElementById("selector1").selectedIndex;
var y = document.getElementById("selector2").selectedIndex;

    report_type = this.report_answer;
    this.selectedIndex = y;
        y=report_type;
    return report_type;

});
});
```